# I want change the 'return' key of iphone virtual key to a another name

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I want change the  'return' key of iphone virtual  key to a another name such as 'Go'. Help me please.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a property

```
@property(nonatomic) UIReturnKeyType returnKeyType;
```

defined in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol.
So what you probably want to do is:

```
UITextField *myTextField; // your textfield..
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

For other possible values see `UIReturnKeyType`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

Comment: Thats cool! But, Is their any way to add completely customized name such as "Open"?

Comment: There's no official way to do this. You could try to traverse the view hierarchy and find the view that represents the button & manipulate it. I haven't tried this yet but it might work. But it is also doomed to break when there are changes to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Its ok. I am not going to break anything.

Comment: How to traverse the view hierarchy of the iphone view system at runtime?

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of that GO key?

Comment: Gopinath: call `-superView` on a view, then loop through its `subviews` array to see its subviews. If you do this on a `UIScrollView`, for example, you will see the content view plus the scroll views, which are private.