# iOS Phonegap change softkeyboard return key

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, soft-keyboard

I want to change the 'return' key of phonegap iOS app. I googled and found it is possible using native code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872218/i-want-change-the-return-key-of-iphone-virtual-key-to-a-another-name). But how can I do same for phonegap application?

Comment: Write a Phonegap plugins. For details, probably other people can fill in for you.

Comment: yes I can, but problem is The UITextField and UITextView classes only support UITextInputTraits protocol.

Comment: Sorry, just realize it is not possible to change the return key from HTML. One other possibility is to place a real UITextField over the HTML and implement a plugin to trigger the native code for it. I'm not sure how complicate it is to do this, though.